# JavaScript Upload script - How do i pass on a pId?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, upload

I am using an upload-plugin for CakePHP and i managed to modify it to  write the paths, resize the image and save the image. But now I want to pass on a pId variable (an int) to the function where i save the image.

This is how it works: 
1) There is a addpictures.ctp with the following:

```
$result = $this->Upload->upload('Projects/'.$projects['Project']['id'], $this->Form->field['Project.id'], $projects['Project']['id']);
    echo $result;
```

This just works fine. (Note that i added a third argument, the project ID.)
2) The function being called looks like this:

```
public function upload($model, $id, $pId){
        $result =  $this->edit($model, $id, $pId);
        return $result;
    }
```

This is inside Pluging/AjaxMultiUpload/View/Helper/UploadHelper.php

3) Now the edit function (in the same file) looks like this:

```
public function edit ($model, $id, $pId) {
    require_once (ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . "/Plugin/AjaxMultiUpload/Config/bootstrap.php");


$dir = Configure::read('AMU.directory');
        if (strlen($dir) < 1) {
                    $dir = "files";
                }

        $webroot = Router::url("/") . "ajax_multi_upload";
        // Replace / with underscores for Ajax controller
        $lastDir = str_replace ("/", "___", 
            $this->last_dir ($model, $id));
        $str = <<<END
            <br /><br />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$webroot/css/fileuploader.css" />
            <script src="$webroot/js/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <div id="AjaxMultiUpload">
                <noscript>
                     <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
                </noscript>
            </div>
            <script src="$webroot/js/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script>        
                function createUploader(){            
                    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                        element: document.getElementById('AjaxMultiUpload'),
                        action: '$webroot/uploads/upload/$lastDir/',
                                                pid: '$pId',
                        debug: true
                    });           
                }
                window.onload = createUploader;     
            </script>
END;
                $str .= $this->view ($model, $id, true);
        return $str;
}
```

Now this is where i added the following:

```
pid: '$pId',
```

As you can see to the creation of the instance.
Now this script is where the magic happens and where i lose overview.
The script is really long, excuse me but i dont really know what to do...

---

### http://jsfiddle.net/sbX8a/

And somewhere here i would like to get the $pId i passed in the Helper.

How do i achieve this?

I am totally lost and after 2 days staring and screwing around with it i am lost.

Greetings,
Harm.

Bump?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, edit your uploader code

```
            function createUploader(){            
                var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                    element: document.getElementById('AjaxMultiUpload'),
                    action: '$webroot/uploads/upload/$lastDir/',
                    debug: true,
                    params: {
                        pid: 123,
                        another: "asd"
                    }
                });           
            }
```

Comment: Tried it out and on line  1198 i added the following to check
alert(params['pid']);
But it alerts Undifined

Comment: `params` is not an array so you can't use `params['pid']`, it's an object so you'll have to use `params.pid` to use it

Comment: I did change it to params.pid and i still get the same result. Sorry to bother you more.

Comment: Could someone please reply again? its still not working and i really dont know what to do